# Can I export conf source code in org-mode to aconf in LaTeX/pdf/minted?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

Emacs org-mode source-code blocks (between `#+begin_src conf` and `#+end_src`) support the `conf` "language"/style with syntax highlighting, but this is not supported when exporting to LaTeX/pdf, which uses the minted LaTeX package.  Instead, LaTeX/minted gives nice results when using the `aconf` style, which doesn't look nice in org-mode itself.

Apart from filing a feature request, is there a quick fix/workaround where the `conf` style in org-mode is exported as `aconf` in LaTeX, or where the `aconf` style in org-mode gets the same status as the `conf` style?  Or is there perhaps another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try customizing `org-latex-minted-langs`. This variable maps symbols (e.g. the symbol `conf` as used in your source block) to a minted "language" (e.g. the string "aconf").

The doc string of the variable (`C-h v org-latex-minted-langs`) says:

> Alist mapping languages to their minted language counterpart.
> The key is a symbol, the major mode symbol without the "-mode".
> The value is the string that should be inserted as the language
> parameter for the minted package.  If the mode name and the
> listings name are the same, the language does not need an entry
> in this list - but it does not hurt if it is present.
>
> Note that minted uses all lower case for language identifiers,
> and that the full list of language identifiers can be obtained
> with:
>
> pygmentize -L lexers

The doc string also conveniently provides a `Customize` link. Click on that and add an entry by clicking on the `INS` button at the end and entering `conf` as the major mode and `aconf` as the minted language. Click on `Apply` at the top and try it out. If it works, click on `Apply and Save` and you are done.

Comment: Great, that does exactly what I wanted.  The same can be achieved by adding `(add-to-list 'org-latex-minted-langs '(conf "aconf"))` to `init.el` or `.emacs`.

Comment: Indeed - this is a simple case, so you don't need the Customize interface (but that is definitely not always the case, so using it by default is the safer option).

Comment: True, but this way the new option is **added** to the default ones, rather than overwriting the default with itself plus the new option.  If the default changes, the new values would be lost.  BTW, I noticed that in my orgmode version (9.5) the variable is called `org-latex-minted-langs` rather than `org-latex-minted-languages`.

Comment: It is indeed `org-latex-minted-langs`: fixed - thanks!